# Python unit test with coverage cross references?

Tags: python, unit-testing, test-coverage

Which unit testing tool in Python that can generate cross-references in coverage reports? For example, it can say for line 4567 in `foo.py` was hit by tests A, B, and C.

I've tried [nose-cov](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-cov/) but in its HTML report it only colors the lines to indicate they were hit. However it does not say which unit test that exercises those lines.

Preferably a tool one that works with Python 3.